# NDepend Linq mixing the output of one query with another

Tags: c#, linq, ndepend

I'd like to restrict the queries from NDepend to a specific set of types. But I get the following error if I try to use a normal assignment:

> ```
>  Only single statement queries are supported.  If you
>  wish to define a function or a variable global to the query, use a
>  range variable defined in a 'let' clause declared before the query.
>  For example:
>
>  let myVar = ThirdParty.Types.WithName("IDisposable").Single() let
>  myFunc = new Func<IType, bool>(t => t.NbLinesOfCode > 10) let ... from
>  t in Types where t.Implement(myVar) && myFunc(t) select new { t,
>  t.NbLinesOfCode }
> ```

But my second attempt fails as well

```
let temp = from t in Types 
let depth0 = t.DepthOfIsUsedBy("PrintOddsDrawing")
where depth0  >= 0 orderby depth0
select new { t, depth0, t.NbTypesUsed }



// <Name>Methods too complex - critical</Name>
warnif count > 0 from m in JustMyCode.Methods where 
  m.CyclomaticComplexity > 30 ||
  m.ILCyclomaticComplexity > 60 ||
  m.ILNestingDepth > 6
  orderby m.CyclomaticComplexity descending,
          m.ILCyclomaticComplexity descending,
          m.ILNestingDepth descending
select new { m, m.CyclomaticComplexity, 
                m.ILCyclomaticComplexity,
                m.ILNestingDepth  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `warnif count > 0` header at the beginning of the query

```
warnif count > 0 
let temp = from t in Types 
...
```

---

Second question:  *Is there also a way to apply all the code smell investigation only to a reduced subset connected with the types I'm working on*

You can do a query like (replace `TypesAndMembers.WithNameLike("m")` with your own subset definition)

```
let subset = TypesAndMembers.WithNameLike("m").ToHashSet()
from i in Issues
where i.CodeElement.IsTypeOrMember &&
       subset.Contains(i.CodeElement)
select new { i, i.Debt, i.Severity }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there also a way to apply all the code smell investigation only to a reduced subset connected with the types I'm working on?

Comment: see the answer to your second question